# Show camera feed in UIView using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift2, avfoundation

I am trying to show the camera's feed in a UIView. Later I need to be able to analyze video frames, so I need to do this using AVFoundation, as I understand.

What I have so far:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var camView: UIView!

    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var videoCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    var input: AnyObject?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        do {
            input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            print("video device error")
        }
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.addInput(input as! AVCaptureInput)
        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = camView.layer.bounds
        captureSession?.startRunning()
    }
}
```

The `camView` is visible, but it doesn't show anything.

The app asked for permission to use the camera at first run, and have been granted that permission.

Setting a breakpoint and inspecting `captureSession`, `videoPreviewLayer`, `videoCaptureDevice` and `input` confirms they have all been set.

Comment: what do u mean by The camView is visible, but it doesn't show anything. ? camera is not shown in the camView ? Start the camera in viewDidAppear not in viewDidload.

Comment: move the line captureSession?.startRunning() into viewDidAppear.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Setting a background color on `camView` confirms that the view is actually on screen - it just doesn't show the camera feed. Moving `captureSession?.starRunning()` to `viewDidAppear` makes no difference.

Comment: i hope u r testing it on device. Did you check if camera permission is turned on for your app in the settings ?

Comment: Try to move  videoPreviewLayer?.frame = camView.layer.bounds and 
        captureSession?.startRunning() to viewDidAppear.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yes, I am running the app on an iPhone, and the permission to use the camera is set. Moving `videoPreviewLayer?.frame = camView.layer.bounds` also makes no difference.

Comment: try to follow this: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/taking-control-of-the-iphone-camera-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/

Comment: you forgot to add the camera layer to the camView.

Comment: add this line camView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The video preview layer is not added to the camView. Hence you cannot see the camera session running in the camView.

Add this line:

```
    camView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you for your help, I have been starring myself blind at this for hours.